# How to disable new doc menu OWA2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, owa

I want to use Office Web Apps 2013 (WAC 2013) with sharepoint 2013 in order to view doc only ( not editing )
I want to disable the below menu ( forcing users to upload files only )

[image]

Comment: We don't see any relation with OWA (outlook web app which is Exchange 2013) here. Screenshot explains only that you want to hide "creation of new items". Can you please elaborate your exact issue?

Comment: Well, I think the question is valid and clear! This menu only shows when SharePoint is connected to Office Web Apps Server 2013 (WAC 2013) or Office Online Server 2016 (OOS 2016).

Comment: Yes, Office web app 2013 was missing. and leading to confusion

Comment: Agreed and corrected

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by simply creating your custom permission level and setting it up for your document Library. You need 2 actions:

> 1. Allow only upload files but no Edit.

(Go to Site Settings-> PSite permissions->Permission Level->create Permission level).[image]

> 2. Hide library new button from both ribbon and top bar

Use below script using script editor web part on your library

```
<style type=text/css>
 #Ribbon.Documents.New.NewDocument-Large, #QCB1_Button1{
   display: none;
 }  
 </style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple, just enable the option **Allow management of content types** on the Advanced Settings page of the document library.

[image: Advanced Settings]

Comment: This not worked for me. I am still able to create all the kind of document..

Comment: I think this only works with SharePoint 2013! For SharePoint Online the menu is always there and will actually integrate with custom content types.

Comment: I thought the same...

Comment: Strangely, this at least has worked with SPO, but apparently isn't the case anymore.

Answer (score 5):

DvG's answer covers the user permission for "Upload only", +1 for that already. The CSS-change given along hides the New-button which should totally restrict the actions available below the "New"-button.

However, if you still want to have the button there for the "New folder"-functionality, the CSS's should only hide the other available options and leave the "New folder"-button untouched. It can be done like this:

```
#cojs-newdocWOPI-WPQ1_callout a:nth-child(-n+4){
    display: none !Important;
}
#cojs-newdocWOPI-WPQ1_callout hr{
    display: none;
}
```

**Outcome**:

[image]